# possible i can let my user to name the text file themself?

Tags: java

normally we write the file writer command with provide the file path and also the name of the text file for user.
example: create a assignment text file

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(".......\assignment");
```

but is it possible that let my user to name the text file them self?

because my program need let lecturer enter bibliographic details about the key reading for an assignment, so lecturer can name the text file by the name with assignment.

Comment: Yes. Prompt the user for the name. Pass that `String` to the `FileWriter` constructor.

Comment: may show mw how to Pass that String to the FileWriter constructor?

Comment: @user3539809 simple google search will show you many examples. For instance, [here's one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_filewriter_class.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your writing a console application, not a GUI one.

In this case use something like the following:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileChooser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(chooseFile());
        // Use your FileWriter
    }

    public static File chooseFile() {
        String fname = null;
        File file = null;

        System.out.println("Please choose file name:");
        while (true) {
            try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
                // Reads a single line from the console
                fname = in.nextLine();
                file = new File(fname);
                if (!file.createNewFile()) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("File already exist");
                }
                break;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + ", please try again:");
            }
        }

        return file;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you are writing a `Swing` GUI, you can use [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html):

```
    //Create a file chooser
    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(parentComponent);

    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    } else {
        // User canceled the file chooser.
    }
```

Comment: i writing a gui application with netbean~XD

Comment: I'm not sure why you accepted @Elliott Frisch 's answer if you are...

Comment: just a mistake, because what i saw it logic...

may you show me how to do it using gui?

what i had did is  
    String name = jTextField1.getText();
             FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(name);

but i want the file path is same for all user, mean i only allow the user to change the name

Comment: Is it a `swing` GUI? Or AWT?

Comment: swing GUI,i created a textfield to let user enter the name of file. Besides that, i create a button to execute it

Comment: See my edited answer for how to use `JFileChooser`. If you want to use the textfield instead, you can do something like `actionPerformed() {String fileName = myTextField.getText();}`

Comment: which comment i have to use so i can set a default file path for use?
which mean the file chooser is open...the file path ard in the path that folder i want to save these text

Comment: Use `JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(String path)` before showing the FileChooser.

Answer (score 2):

Using a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) you might pass a user provided `String` to the [`FileWriter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String%29) constructor with something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a file name: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scan.next();
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(str)) {

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

To use a file in the user's home directory, you might use

```
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), str))) {

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thx for reply, but may i allow the user to name the text file only, but with default file path?

Comment: @user3539809 Edited to give an example with a default path relative to the user's home. You can use something else as a base.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Scanner` to get the file name from the keyboard. If you are using command prompt for taking file name then you can use the following code -

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String fileName = input.next();
```

Then pass the `'fileName'` to the `PrintWriter` constructor.

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
writer.close();
```